# Using xml from Android Studio on Xamarin

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have just started learning Xamarin and started importing my project from Android Studio manually to Xamarin on VS 2015.

I have noticed that Xamarin gives an error on certain UI elements like FloatingActionButton, DrawerLayout or anything from Android.Support library.

what should I configure on Xamarin to use these UI elements?
If that is not possible, then what are the alternatives for Xamarin?

Comment: You shouldn't have to. These elements should be the same in both Android Studio and Visual Studio. You may want to ensure that your respective libraries are correctly installed.

Answer (score 2):

You have to install the nuget packages for the used support libraries.

e.g. support v4 for the DrawerLayout:

```
Install-Package Xamarin.Android.Support.v4
```

here is a list of all available libs:

https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=Xamarin+support

You can find them in the NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio, too.

Answer (score 2):

There is a nice extension for Visual Studio, [XamarIDEA (Visual Studio Gallary)](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9f5a516a-f4d0-4228-9d25-d0273abebf33).
It allows you to easily work with XML layouts in Android Studio. Changes to XML files in Android studio are synchronized with the XML files in your Visual Studio Android Project.

Supports all XML Android files not just layout (color, styles, drawables, anim etc.)

It however does not support Xaml files. Any Xaml file in your project will be convert to XML to be able to use in Android studio. One caveat though is that it does not support previewing of custom controls (3rd party or your own making).

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing references in your new project. For `DrawerLayout` you need to reference `Xamarin.Android.Support.v4` dll. For FloatingActionButton add [Android Support Design Library](https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/xamandroidsupportdesign) :

> Install-Package Xamarin.Android.Support.Design -Version 23.2.1

Comment: How do I reference this .dll file in my VS project? This information is not given in the link.

Comment: You can install it from nuget

Comment: The Xamarin Android Designer does not render custom Views. However, this answer is correct if you didn't add the references and it is throwing errors at compile time.